# Cypress click button fail (detached from DOM), but dom.isDetached is false

Tags: javascript, html, cypress

My test code is like this:

```
cy.contains('.InovuaReactDataGrid__cell','CypressWarehouse').siblings().find('button').click(); //fail, detached from the DOM
cy.contains('.InovuaReactDataGrid__cell','CypressWarehouse').siblings().find('button').then(($el)=>{
    assert.isFalse(Cypress.dom.isDetached($el), 'not detached'); //pass
    $el.click(); //not work
});
```

I don't understand why click() fails because "this element is detached from the DOM", but if I use Cypress.dom.isDetached it returns false.

Also, `$el.click()` not work, it throw an exception of "ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded"
The button I intend to click is an ant dropdown trigger. If I manually click it a dropdown menu will be seen. But neither code above can show me the dropdown menu.

[image: cypress]

Answer (score 1):

Usually with dropdown menus I use `realClick()` otherwise try `$el.click({force: true})`

Comment: I tried, it had no exceptions or errors, but still the dropmenu did not show. I think I need to keep the mouse on the button.

Comment: Did you by any chance try 'realClick({force: true})' ? It has happened to me where the dropdown does not show, but the options in the dropdown are available to click

Comment: It seems `realClick` did not click the button, there is no purple border.

Comment: I add a wait in the beginning and now `click` works. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may have two `click()` handlers, one for the row and one for the action button.

Try selecting the row first

```js
cy.contains('.InovuaReactDataGrid__cell', 'CypressWarehouse')
  .parent()
  .click()

// requery in case DOM changed on first click 
cy.contains('.InovuaReactDataGrid__cell', 'CypressWarehouse')
  .parent()
  .find('button')
  .click()
```